# latin modern math italic font

Tags: math-mode, italic, latin-modern

I'm trying to use exactly the same fonts for other software as when using the **lmodern package** in latex.

All seems to work fine after having downloaded the latin modern fonts, as well as the latin modern **math** fonts from http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/lm-math/download/index_html respectively, with one exception: greek symbols in italic.

For some reason, the latin modern math fonts do not contain an italic font set for me. Reasons?

- Is this a problem with my OS (mac os X sierra)?
- Am I doing something wrong (basically just open the included .otf files and import them into the font book)?
- Any other reason?

Thanks in advance and best regards, Manuel

Edit: My question is very likely a stupid novice question: I assumed importing the .otf file of Latin Modern Math into the Apple Font Book, would somehow give me access to greek letters in italic (the same when typesetting a latex document with greek letters in math mode and using the lmodern package). I hoped that I could then access the greek italic font via for example simply choosing a font in microsoft word. For other fonts such as Euclid, different font types are included as shown in the two pictures attached, while for Latin Modern Math only a regular type seems to be included.

What am I doing wrong? Or am I asking the wrong question? Thanks again!

**Top**: Euclid Symbol font in Apple's Font Book: includes several different font types.

**Bottom**: Latin Modern Math font in Apple's Font Book, only containing a regular font, no italic.

[image: Top: Euclid Symbol font in Apple's Font Book: includes several different font types. Bottom: Latin Modern Math font in Apple's Font Book, only containing a regular font, no italic.]

Comment: it is not clear what you did but math italic starts at U+1D434 ()

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- why are you citing the unicode math italic?  latin modern math italic should be fonts named `lmmi*`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton the lm-math link provided by the OP is to the opentype math font with a MATH table and the math alphabets in plane 1. (That is also almost certainly what is wanted if using the fonts in other software rather than the classic tex encoded fonts packaged for pdftex)

Comment: Manuel, as the comments between @barbarabeeton and myself hint there are two versions of latin modern, one using unicode opentype fonts where all the math is in a single font (with as I indicated the math italic at U+1D434 and following) and another completely different set of fonts which are packaged as a set of 8bit fonts suitable for use with classic tex and pdftex. it isn't clear which you tried (both sets are available from the GUST site that you link to)

Comment: David and @barbarabeeton -- thanks for your input. I added some more information to what I'm trying to do in the original post. It is probably more along Davids line, however Im not sure how to access a character like U+1D434 in for example a microsoft word document. In any case, thanks.

Comment: The main misunderstanding of the OP is that in contrast to Knuth’s fonts (e.g. cmr10 and cmmi10)  the mathematical versions of the utf8-fonts (e.g. latinmodern-math) contain multiple variations of most letters. E.g. there is the “Latin Small Letter A” a and the “Mathematical Italic Small A” . To use italics, you have to enter the “Mathematical Italic…” codes.